# How can I save attachments to folders other than the root in Google Drive?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, gmail, email-attachments

I am using the google script described [here](http://ctrlq.org/code/19053-send-to-google-drive).

```
This Google Apps Script will automatically save Gmail attachments to Google Drive.
```

I have altered some parameters in the script such as the trigger time altering it to 1 minute, but nothing more drastical. I have also created a sample Google sheet to test the script. Here is a "copy" of it:

```
A    |   B     |    C    |     D
Designate label:         |   Inbox
Destination folder:      |   GMail
Checkout label:          |   GDrive
```

The script is working as expected, taking any new attachments from the inbox and saving it in the `Gmail` folder under ROOT in my Google Drive (also called My Drive).

Let's suppose I have a destination folder in my Root called `Work Files/Mails/Attachments/` How can I modify the sheet (or should I modify the script instead?) to save under that new destination folder?

Comment: change `Destination folder:` ***GMail*** to **Work Files/Mails/Attachments/** on spreadsheet

Comment: @iJay I have already tried that, it creates a folder named Work Files/Mails/Attachments/ in the root folder.

Comment: try another name, without slash **/**

Comment: If I give it any other name, for example if I try with name "Example" it creates a folder named "Example" in the root directory. If the folder already exists in the root directory (For example "Work Files") it saves the attachments in that folder.

Comment: yes,code checks whether there is a folder on root, if not create one and save attachments on it.if there is a folder attachments will save in it.

Comment: The problem lies in the fact that I don't want it to save to a folder in the root direction, but to a folder nested inside other folders.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101915/discussion-between-ijay-and-theocharis-k).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use folder ID instead of folder name.

```
//ID -> Files/Mails/Attachments/ 
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FOLDER ID");  
var file = folder.createFile(file);
```

In your sheet put your folder id.